# ListBox with multiselect property loses selected items

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, multi-select

I need to change a filter in a PivotTable based on a ListBox with multiselect property = 1 - fmMultiSelectMulti, but when I run my VBA code items that are selected in the ListBox lose the selection.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub BtnAtualizarLiberty_Click()
    With Sheets("Liberty_Data").PivotTables("DinamicaLiberty1").PivotFields("RSCORE_CGV6")
                    .EnableMultiplePageItems = True
                    For Z = 1 To .PivotItems.Count
                        .PivotItems(Z).Visible = False
                        For r = 0 To ListRiscoScoreLiberty.ListCount - 1
                            If ListRiscoScoreLiberty.Selected(r) = True And ListRiscoScoreLiberty.List(r) = .PivotItems(Z).Value Then
                                .PivotItems(Z).Visible = True
                            End If
                        Next
                    Next
                End With
      End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem. I was filling the listbox with a pivot table data and when I was changing the pivot fields filter at the any others pivot table, the listbox lost all the selected items.

So, now I'm filling the listbox 'manually', I've made a sheet called "Filters" and I've filled a column with all listbox row and it has solved the problem.

Sorry for the bad english.